# Clang-format use formatted file name in include regex

Tags: c, clang, include, header-files, clang-format

Consider the following includes in the file `Main.c`

```
#include "Main.h"
#include "Main_something.h"
#include "Main_anotherthing.h"
#include "Main_randomString.h"
#include "Something_FromAnotherLib.h"
```

I want to make `clang-format` consider everything that starts with `Main` (the formatted file name) as a main header and assign it a category of 0.

`clang-format` offers [the opposite of what I need](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#includeismainregex). It allows you to specify a bunch of source file suffixes which also count as main files. I.e. `Main_myThing.c` is considered to be named `Main.c` for the purpose of includes sorting. I need to be able to specify a bunch of header name suffixes which are to be considered "main". I.e. `Main_mything.h` == `Main.h` for the purposes of the include sorting.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: It's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use any "predefined magic values" in this regexp
Take a look at https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/HeaderIncludes_8cpp_source.html

```cpp
CategoryRegexs.emplace_back(Category.Regex
...
if (CategoryRegexs[i].match(IncludeName))
```

But, if you want, you can do something like this. Create template .clang-format.tmpl file,

```
IncludeCategories
  - Regex: '${placeholder}.*'
```

and propagate it by script in each subfolder .clang-format with replacing `${placeholder}` with `Main_` or `$0/` or any other.